# How do I store a pointer (node) returned by a function to my main?

Tags: c, linked-list

I currently completed my function to reverse a linked list, but when I return a pointer to the head of the new linked list I am getting errors because I am storing it wrong in my main. Can someone explain to me the proper syntax to store and print the newly linked list?

```
typedef struct Node {
   int val;
   struct Node * next;
}LL_t;

LL_t reverse(LL_t* ls) // passing me a head
{

   \\ my code

   return ls; // pretty sure this is how I return the new head node 
}

int main() {

 \\ my code

   LL_t *p = reverse(head); // not working, giving me these weird incompatible errors.

   for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
   {
         printf( "*(p + %d) : %d\n", i, *(p + i));
   }
   return 0;   
}
```

Here is my final error after changing my variable pointer p and attempting to printf it

int *p;
p = reverse(head)

Error;

main.c:42:6: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    p = reverse(head);

Edit2:

I tried tis approach, but not workin for me:

```
   for (p->val != NULL)
   {
        printf("%d\n", p->val);
        p->val = p->next;
   }
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what the error is? Also where is `head` coming from?

Comment: Let me take a screen shot.

Comment: yeah, sory i couldn't upload, says pic was too large,

Comment: Copy and paste.  Don't take a screenshot.

Comment: "I am getting errors" If you think they are relevant, show them. If you think they are not, don't mention them. "Let me take a screen shot". Don't. Use text. Your compiler outputs text, not pictures.

Comment: Alright, I just copied and pasted the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LL_t reverse(LL_t* ls) { }
```

Takes a pointer, but returns a structure. You need:

```
LL_t *reverse(LL_t* ls) { }
```

Comment: Thanks,how do I fix the prinf statment? it keeps saying it expects an integer, but i am giving it an LL-t. I fixed it somehow, but now it gives me a warning when I change p to int *p

Comment: @BeginnerC printf can't print an LL_t. Perhaps you want to print the `val` member, in which case you'd use `p->val`. The next thing you'll need to do is to iterate over the linked list using the `p->next` member instead of looping from 0 to 9 (you can't index a linked list with your `i` variable)

Comment: Two problems there. `*(p + i)` means "the `i`th element of some array of LL_t structs". That is, it's a struct, and no such array exists that I can see. What are you trying to print?

Comment: The elements of my newly reversed linked list.

Comment: I updated my post with what I tried, didn't work well.

Comment: You're still trying to printf a struct. Printf doesn't do structs.

Comment: I see..what should I do to print out elements then?

Comment: You have to do that yourself: name each element you want to print explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are facing issues is because your function is set up to return a LL_t node, not a pointer to it. By fixing the function declaration, your shouldnt face any other errors (at least from the provided code):

```
LL_t* reverse(LL_t* ls) { ...
```

Comment: How do I fix the error with my printf statement? I seemed to have gotten it to work by switchig p to int *p, but I end up with a warning about incompatible types.